# angle between hour minute second hands

Tags: c, algorithm

I am writing a program to calculate the angle between the hour&min hand, hour&sec, minute&second.

I wrote my code but no matter how much I change my calculations I still can't get the answer that this paper wants..

I used a double

```
//I did this to calculate the minute angle precisely since I assume 
//the second hand is also moving and it affects 1degree when it moves to 60..
angleminute=((6.0*minutes)+((1/60.0)*seconds)); 

//Also this to calculate the hour angle, the normal formula is 0.5*minutes
//but i also added the "seconds/60" for more accuracy
anglehour=((30.0*hour12)+(0.5*((seconds/60)+minutes)))

anglesecond=(6.0*seconds) //this is to calculate the second hand angle...
```

Now when i find the difference between these angles i get different results...

For time **11:54:29** here are **my** results

```
Hour-minute= 32.52
Minute-second= 150.48
Second-hour=177.00
```

But the **expected** results are:

```
Hour-minute=30.34
Minute-second= 152.90
Second-hour=176.76
```

How is he getting those results?? I have also tried using the normal method but still can't get the same results. Many formulas but still can't get the same answers...

```
angleminute=6*minutes

anglehour=30*hour+0.5*minutes

anglesecond=6*seconds
```

Comment: What you say _How is he getting those results_ where are **"those"** results? Please post the results you **expect**

Comment: @gideon , Expected results are already posted. Read the post carefully

Comment: @CoolGuy whoops sorry. Needs more formatting I guess :/ Sorry user3564. I edited your question to make things more clearer.

Comment: What kind of watch are you aiming for? Does the minute arm move constantly each second or only when the full minute passes? Same for the hour arm.

Comment: the minute watch moves constantly as the second hand move...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `angleminute` calculation is wrong. It does move 6 degrees for each minute, but each second is 1/60 of a minute, so for each second it moves 1/60 * 6 degrees, not 1/60 degrees.

Also, what are the types of `minutes`, `seconds`, `hour`? If they're `int`s, then there's another problem: in the calculation of `anglehour`, `(seconds/60)` will be integer division, and will come out as `0`. You need `(seconds/60.0)`.

Comment: Thanks a lot..  i never noticed the 6, I also had to fix the hour hand too to become anglehour=(30*hour)+0.5(minutes+seconds/60.0) which brougt me the exact answer that i wanted